# Visualisation of 3D DICOM Images in C#

Tags: c#, .net, 3d, vtk, dicom

I'm developing an application that displays DICOM Images and also does Multi Planar Reconstruction, that works just fine, now, I'm going into 3D now (Skin).

What would be the best alternative? I've read about VTK but I'm not pretty sure, is there some examples out there I can reference?

Answer (score 1):

This is the open source code you need:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/466955/Medical-image-visualization-using-WPF

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this [leadtools] (http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/medical/dicom.htm)

Comment: Well, that's pretty expensive, I'm looking for another type of opensource code or library I could use.. Thanks

Comment: Yeah it's insanely expensive.  But commercial PACS products and viewers are generally priced as such so they can justify it.  Leadtools are excellent.  Have you looked in the offis toolkit? There might be something there that can help.  I have only used it for dicom work lists not for imaging but gut feeling is that you will find something there.  Documentation is awful unfortunately.